# I can see iPod in Ubuntu 16.04.1 but there is no app that can get access to music at all

Tags: 16.04, ipod

Tried gtkpod, Banshee, Rhythmbox, Lollypop, Clementine with no success

[image]

Comment: It won't work. You can try a virtual machine with Windows and iTunes.

Comment: why won't work, is there any official statement that iPods are no longer supported in any other OS exept mac OS or Windows?

and alredy tried Windows in VM but this is even worse because virtualized Windows can't see ipod at all

Comment: 1. Linux was NEVER supported; 2. In a VM you need do a few things before you can *move* USB devices from the host to the guest OS, namely (for Virtualbox) install guest additional and add user. Every pertinent information is available googling.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your device is running IOS7 (or earlier?) it appears that you can resolve this issue my installing the package [libimobiledevice-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libimobiledevice-utils) by enabling the universe repository and issuing these commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libimobiledevice-utils
```

I don't have the hardware to test this but it should put you on the right path.

EDIT: Upon obtaining an Ipod I can verify that it works flawlessly in Rhythmbox with a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installation. You'll find it listed under Devices as shown below. Click the device, then the song you wish to play, then click the play button.

[image: rythmbox]

Comment: already installed - no success :(

Comment: I'll see if I can lay my hands on an IPod...

Comment: @fiii Updated Answer